# CSS syntax regarding extra spaces

Tags: css

How is it possible for CSS to recognize a space as a error?

This will work, for example:
`height: 50px;`

But this doesn't work?:
`height: 50 px;`

Can someone tell me why this is the case? It was really hard to find this error in my `CSS`.

Comment: The problem isn't two consecutive spaces, it's the extra space between `50` and `px`.

Comment: @DCoder lol I've edited

Comment: @TylerH My fault. I assumed SO is only about programming. I checked meta and obviously CSS is considered on topic.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Over 200,000 CSS questions might've been a clue there ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#values) states that, for CSS Level 3, all *non-zero values* must be accompanied by a **unit identifier**, in this case `px`. Adding a space after the value is essentially the same as not adding a **unit identifier** at all. The `CSS` specification treats a space as an instruction that the browser should stop interpreting that property and move on to a new line or property listing.

```
body {
   font-size: 50 px;
}
```

is not okay, since the `CSS` is interpreted as:

What is the element? **`Body.`** Interpret according to spec if possible. There's a space; move on to the next line or property. What is the property? **`Font-size.`** This property needs a value. What is the value of the **`font-size`** property? **`50.`** Interpret according to spec if possible. Move on to the next line or property. Next line says **`px;`**. etc. etc.

So your CSS will be interpreted by the browsers in this way. The specification allows for a space **or** no space between a **property** and a **unit** (`size:50px;` vs `size: 50px;`), so browsers have a use-case for either of those situations. If there is a space between a **unit** and a **unit identifier** (`size:50 px;`), there is no use-case for that, as it is not allowed by the spec. The browser doesn't understand what to do and moves on; the style is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't really error. It either works or it doesn't. `height: 50 px` doesn't work because it doesn't know how to interpret `50 px`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation why? Just "50 px doesn't work" isn't a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value (50 in this case) and unit (px) should be next to each other withour any space in between. But the space between 50 and : is not important and is just for decorative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 50 px;
```

Doesn't work because the browser doesn't know how to interpret it.  Browsers interpret CSS according to the specification...

Just because its a space doesn't mean its okay to put it there.  For example what if you did this in PHP

```
$var iable = 1;
```

Regardless of if you think its right or wrong you have to code to the specification no matter what language you are using